# Azure Function using Python - Blob trigger not firing

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-app

I am working on one of the Azure Function which is written in Python and it should get called based on Blob trigger event. However, the trigger is not firing when I am uploading a zip file in a blob container to which azure function is supposed to monitor.

Following is local.settings.json file -

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": 
    {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "blob (connection string) that was created when Azure function is created",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "My_STORAGE": "blob (connection string) that function should monitor"
    }
}
```

Following is function.json file -

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "mycontainer/{name}",
      "connection": "My_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is my code **init**.py - (test_func is user defined function to do some business logic)

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
test_func(myblob.name)
logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
             f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
             f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

When I'm uploading zip file in "mycontainer" container, the azure function is not firing.

The "mycontainer" of **StorageV2 (general purpose v2)** account kind. I am using **Python 3.8** version.

This "mycontainer" has automatically created a container named $logs that has day wise folder to have a log file mentioning the file that I'm uploading in "mycontainer", however, there is no sign of blob trigger event on Azure function.

"My_STORAGE" is added as Application Settings in Azure Function's Configuration settings. I am uploading **Local Settings** after Azure Function deployment.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you test the function in local ? And could you please check if there is any error when execute `test_func(myblob.name)` ?

Comment: I removed test_func(myblb.name) function. still no luck. Not sure, how would I test this on local?

Comment: Run this command: `func host start` in your VS code Terminal window to start your function.

Comment: And could you please share the content of `My_STORAGE` (use `xxx` to replace the sensitive information of the connection string).

Comment: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mycontainer;AccountKey=xxxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",

Comment: The `AccountName` in connection string should not be the name of container, it should be your storage account name.

Comment: Here is the connection in my local.settings.json: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=hurystorage;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxx=;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`. "hurystorage" is my storage account name, the container which I want to monitor is `mycontainer` and the container name do not need to be added in the connection string.

Comment: yes, changed account name to storage account name and deployed.

Comment: You do not need to re-deploy it to portal, you just need to change the `My_STORAGE` in application settings of your function app on portal. "local.settings.json" will not be deployed to azure portal when you do deployment.

Comment: yes, done that, still no luck :(

Comment: Are you sure you have changed the value of `My_STORAGE` in application settings ?

Comment: yes, Azure Function -> Settings -> Configuration -> update in existing Application settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227268/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-rameshwar-pawale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by mistake in connection string. The `AccountName` in connection string should be storage account name but not the name of container.

So just change `AccountName=mycontainer` to `AccountName=<storage account name>`, then it works.

And by the way:

The connection string should be: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage account name>;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

The "path" in "function.json" should be: `"path": "<container name>/{name}"`

Comment: thanks Hury, indeed the path in function.json was incorrect.

Comment: just a quick question, is the container name within the path supposed to be enclosed with the `<` and `>` symbol ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot @ you. @user3396351 do not need `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem. It was solved by adding the connection string as a key-value pair to the Application Settings in Function App->Configuration->Settings. I assume that it has to be done if Azure Functions Apps are deployed in a different storage container, for which there needs to be a different connection string.

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER! You need to create a key-value pair like this:
<storageaccount>_STORAGE : <connection string for the storage account>

Answer (score 0):

Copy the <storage_account>_STORAGE key from `local.settings.json` file to a new application setting key-value:

[image]